# Sort array by keys in custom order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following multidimensional array

```
[
    'June 2015' => [
        'LOW' => [160.50],
        'MEDIUM' => [0.00],
        'HIGH' => [60.80]
    ],
    'July 2015' => [
        'MEDIUM' => [226.00],
        'HIGH' => [263.00],
        'LOW' => [121.96]
    ]
]
```

I need to sort each of the inner arrays by their key so they are in the order LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH (the first is correct by chance).

I tried the following code which I took and adjusted from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php):

```
function cmp($a, $b){
        $a = preg_replace('@^(LOW|MEDIUM|HIGH) @', '', $a);
        $b = preg_replace('@^(LOW|MEDIUM|HIGH) @', '', $b);
        return strcasecmp($a, $b);
    }

    foreach($live_quotations as $exp_conversion_date => $Aconversion_likelihood){
        foreach($Aconversion_likelihood as $conversion_likelihood => $quotation_values){
    
            uksort($live_quotations[$exp_conversion_date], "cmp");
    
        }
    }
```

but this orders them as HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW (ascending alphabetical). It does not matter if I change the order in the cmp function they are always sorted this way. I don't think I'm understanding this uksort or cmp function correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the following comparison function:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $order = Array( 'LOW' => 0, 'MEDIUM' => 1, 'HIGH' => 2 );
    return $order[$a] - $order[$b];
}
```

Example of this code is [here](http://ideone.com/iMRh5H).

Comment: That example you provided from the PHP manual is removing the words `a`, `an` and `the` from the beginning of the key and using the remainder to provide the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

Because all of your subarrays have all three nominated keys, you can remove some complexity.  The inner loop can be omitted and no sorting algorithm is required. Separately, if you wish to establish default elements when missing, this provides that feature as well.

Below, you establish an ordered array, then overwrite the defaults with each occuring subarray value.  This could be achieved by "modifying by reference", but I am following the style in your posted snippet.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Y7qDr))

```
$ordered_defaults = array_fill_keys(['LOW', 'MEDIUM', 'HIGH'], 0);

foreach ($live_quotations as $date => $likelihoods) {
    $live_quotations[$date] = array_replace($ordered_defaults, $likelihoods);
}

var_export($live_quotations);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'June 2015' => 
  array (
    'LOW' => 
    array (
      0 => 160.5,
    ),
    'MEDIUM' => 
    array (
      0 => 0.0,
    ),
    'HIGH' => 
    array (
      0 => 60.8,
    ),
  ),
  'July 2015' => 
  array (
    'LOW' => 
    array (
      0 => 121.96,
    ),
    'MEDIUM' => 
    array (
      0 => 226.0,
    ),
    'HIGH' => 
    array (
      0 => 263.0,
    ),
  ),
)
```